Should I practice like Chess Grandmaster Ding Liren to get better at chess?
Ding Liren has always been my inspiration, especially so when he won the World Chess Championship. Does anyone know of any openings that he plays commonly and any of his strategies later game?

I would be surprised if a super GM (2700+) player in the top 20 of the world's players has later game strategies except for what the position calls for in the moment. Obviously this is influenced by both the player's openings and to their playing styles.

Practicing like a World Champion means studying and playing chess as a fulltime job.

Out of all of the openings that Ding Liren plays, his stats show that the D37 opening (Queen's Gambit Declined) has the highest win rate for him as white. As black, he has favourable odds in the C54 (Giuoco Piano Opening) and the C88 (Ruy Lopez Opening).

Ofc at grandmaster level the theory is often at least 10+ moves deep, not just playing the first 3 moves of an opening.

agreed, i wish it was only 10 or 15,
many cases i have seen goes to 25, and then everything forced to dead draw, or repetition,

well, we can think about it in to way:
1- it is a good practice to have a one or two favorite player and go through a lot if his/her games in general, in that case you will learn about the Game as a Whole which includes opening, middle game, endgame, tactic, strategy and ...

the old way was to follow a classical player { like Alekhine or Capablanca} since it is easier to understand those games and closer to the level or our play as an amatuers, --but obviously nothing wrong with with following Ding or any one else that you like,

one key topic is you will learn more is you study the entire game, whether if he loses or wins,


2- in terms of opening choice, you can consider him a classical player with the preference toward more solid openings like Queen Gambit Declined, or 1- ...e5 for black and 1-d4 or 1-c4 as white,
there are books and video courses about him games, that you can easily find.
3- and my final note is, according to our rating and our strength and weakness  we can learn or focus on different parts of the game,
so, one practical choice would be to

List item

go quickly over many of him games,

List item
look at his games in a specific opening, i.e. 10  or 20 games in QGD with black

List item
once you got a feeling about his handling of an specific opening, then go and spend at least one or two hours on a game that is been annotated by a human, (not an engine) { of course it is better to be written, like a book or article, but there video courses could be fine too}  and then you can go and play that opening in a quick time format like rapid, practice it and after sometime you can play it in a classical game over the board,


of course that is the beginning of an amazing journey, you study and you will learn, you play it and you learn more, and so on!
wishing you and others who go through this joyful journey a lot of pleasure in learning and discovering!
